# Appending a div with a class id and image to a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been struggling with this for a few days now. I would like to append a div with class id and an image to my container I have been able to render the cards, but upon inspecting the HTML in dev tools I came across this

```
<div class="hidden-container card-image" id="card-id-1" "=""> 
<img src="../images/avatar.png" <="" div="">
</div>
```

what surprises me is the empty `=` `<=` and empty `div`. These should obviously not be here.

I render the divs like so

```
    $.each(cards, function (index, props) {
        $("#card-area").append('<div class="hidden-container card-image" id=card-id-' + props.Id + ' "> <img src="' + props.Url + '"</div>');
    });
```

Would anyone be able to properly format this ? it has been giving me a headache for the last couple of days.

Comment: Use something llike this ```$("#card-area").append(`<div class="hidden-container card-image" id="card-id-${props.Id}"> <img src="${props.Url}" /></div>`);```

Comment: You have not closed img tag.

Comment: I recommend using handlebars , doing string append may lead to less maintainable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You missed `"` around `id`

2.You missed to close `<img>` tag as well

```
$.each(cards, function (index, props) {
  $("#card-area").append('<div class="hidden-container card-image" id="card-id-' + props.Id + ' "> <img src="' + props.Url + '"></div>');
});
```

Comment: @nielsvanhoof  glad to help you:)

Answer (score 1):

forget to close `img`-tag

```
<div class="hidden-container card-image" id="card-id-1" "=""> 
   <img src="../images/avatar.png" <="" div="">
   </img>
</div>
```

and the marks by `id="card-id-'`

```
$.each(cards, function (index, props) {
    $("#card-area").append('<div class="hidden-container card-image" id="card-id-' + props.Id + ' "> <img src="' + props.Url + '"</div>');
});
```